# Best practice to update large number of rows in Cassandra reliably (relational update)

Tags: cassandra

I have a few tables that are related to each other, it looks something like this:

```
organizations: 
- id
- name
- ... other fields

users:
- id
- name
- organization_id
- organization_name
- ... other fields
```

I keep `organization_name` field in the `users` table so that it doesn't have to look up to organization to get the organization name

The problem is that if organization name is changed, all users related to the organization must be updated to reflect the new name. In my real scenario there are more tables where I store `organization_name` on.

**Problem**: Currently I just fire up the update statement asynchronously and if it fails halfway then I'll end up with inconsistent data

**Question**: Is there a best practice how to deal with this sort of issue?

**Possible solutions**:

- Using `BATCH` statement. But I found it very limiting since by default it only allows 50kb query size (in my case 1 update might lead up to updating 8,000 other entities from two or three different tables with varying length in the field values - so query size is rather unpredictable)

  - I actually tried using `BATCH` statement to update 100 items (out of 600 that needs to be updated) and it failed with "Batch Size Too Large" exception...
- Retry on failed update

*PS* - my rows are not too wide, at most I have about 20 columns per table

---

*Update:*

Forgot to add, this is a webapp where update needs to be reflected as soon as possible, so batch job won't be applicable

---

*Update 2:*

Regarding read pattern, my current example is oversimplified, but in any case I would require to fetch list of users (it can be from multiple organizations) - this might return over thousands of users over hundreds of organizations which is why I stored `organization_name` in the `users` table as my understanding is that with Cassandra data denormalization is the way to go

Comment: What are your read patterns? Why do you want to avoid look up organization name by user? If you want to display info about one user, it will be better  to have one additional request  to get organization name instead of support consistency between many tables.

Comment: @MikhailBaksheev I updated the question to include more details. I agree if displaying for one user, it doesn't make sense to store organization name :-)

Comment: What field are you going to fetch users by? or all users?

Comment: Read my answer as: "Update all your records in groups of X records. Choose X to best reflect your needs. Run multiple 'group updates' consecutively like if you should update all your records at once, but simply bookmark each group just to be able to resume if something goes wrong." Is this not "as soon as possible"?

Comment: @MikhailBaksheev It's not based on the fields, let's say I get the list of user ids from elasticsearch based on a query. This might return hundreds/thousands of users from different organizations

Comment: @xmas79 when you say groups of X records do you mean to group it in a `BATCH` statement or just run the update queries asynchronously?

Comment: No batches, just async. And design your queries to be idempotent so you can run them again, and again, and again...

Comment: @xmas79 I guess that's the only way I suppose.. I'll keep the question opened for few more days to see if someone can come up with other solution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like in every long-running update process, you should use the concept of *bookmark*:

- Run *jobs* of (say 100) async updates and then store somewhere that you just done updating 100 rows.
- Run another job of another 100 rows and then bookmark you've just updated 200 rows.
- And so on...

In the event of a crash, you will just resume where you crashed by reading your bookmark.

To perform such task you must already know what records you have to update, but I'm assuming you already know them or know how to retrieve that information.

Answer (score 2):

Try to work with paging. Most drivers support it.

1) Receive the results for update from users table, with paging of x row in each page.

2) Run async update for each record in the page.

3) Move to next page.